# Data Migration : What way is the best way to Migrate?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, data-migration

I am doing data migration two database in MS SQL 2005. The records are more than 200000 nearly 300000. I need to query from source database using joins and insert 2 or 3 tables in destination databse.

Which way is the best way to do so? Please suggest me. I am trying to write a program with VB.NET. If you have sample, please show me the way how to.

Thanks in advance,
RedsDevils

Comment: Do you need any vb.net logic or is it simply moving data from the source to a slightly different structure in the destination?

Comment: yes slightly different structure. but i need to verify the data is correct or  not. Some data in source can be wrong data.

Comment: More than two million and nearly 300-thousand are mutually exclusive. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the issue with the source data well defined?  If so, then you can just use [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx), and query from one database and insert into the target filtering out the bad data using your select query.  This would remove the need to write anything in .NET...

Comment: Linked Servers is for Different Server? How can I access different Databases in Same Server?

Comment: You can do that by ensuring you have access to both databases on your current connection, and then prefix the table names with the names of the databases you need.  i.e. INSERT INTO Database2.dbo.Table1 (fieldnames) SELECT * FROM Database1.dbo.Table1